# Where is DMOZ data available now?

Tags: data-request

I learned from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMOZ) that [DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org/) is no longer maintained. Where can I get the earlier DMOZ site directory data? or is there a similar data source?

Thank you so much.

Edit:
I found something [here](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/OMV93V), seems like it's valid.

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, write that in an answer, not in the question. You can also fix 'DOMZ' at the same time ;-)

Comment: @JanDoggen fixed :) thank you for the suggestion. I'm still hoping someone comes up with a better answer than that, if not I'll turn it into an answer

Comment: BTW If you read that Wikpedia page, you see you can go to dmoztools.net or https://curlie.org/

Answer (score 3):

I found parsed DMOZ data at Harvard site.  You can try here: https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/OMV93V